# Chi squared test for significance

Tags: r, chi-squared

I want to report on the difference between males and female fish in migration tactics. Would this be a chi-squared test?
This is my data:

```
combo1 <- structure(list(Sex = c("F", "M", "F", NA, "M", "F", NA, NA, "M", 
"F", NA, "M", "F", "F", NA, "F", "F", NA, "M", "F", NA, "M", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", NA, "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M", 
"F", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "F", "F", NA, NA, NA, "M", "F", 
"F", NA, "F", "F", NA, NA, "M", "F", NA, "F", NA, "M", NA, "F", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "F", "M", "M", NA, "F"), Tactic = c("Migr", "Migr", 
"Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", 
"Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "OcRes", "Migr", "Migr", 
"Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "OcRes", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", 
"Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", 
"Migr", "EstRes", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", 
"Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", 
"Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "EstRes", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "EstRes", 
"Migr", "OcRes", "Migr", "EstRes", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", 
"Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-72L))
```

Table for Sex Proportions

```
Sex<-combo1 %>% 
    filter(!Sex%in%NA) %>% 
    droplevels() %>% 
    count(Sex,Tactic) %>% 
    group_by(Sex) %>%
    mutate(Proportion = n / sum(n)) %>%
    mutate(Tactic = factor(Tactic, levels = c("EstRes", "OcRes", "Migr"))) %>% 
    mutate(Sex = factor(Sex, levels = c("F", "M")))
Sex
```

```
Sex Tactic  n   Proportion

F   EstRes  1   0.03448276  
F   Migr    26  0.89655172  
F   OcRes   2   0.06896552  
M   Migr    15  1.00000000
```

I have a ggplot that show's these results nicely, but I am not sure how to get a p-value to support these results. Would it be a chi-squared test and if so what would the script be? I have looked here https://data-flair.training/blogs/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2018/01/R-Code.jpg and tried this script:

```
chisq.test(combo1$Sex, combo1$Tactic, correct=FALSE)
```

which produced this result:

```
Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  combo1$Sex and combo1$Tactic
X-squared = 1.6653, df = 2, p-value = 0.4349.
```

But I'm not sure if it is correct. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have to paste the output from `dput(combo1)`. That is what gives us the data. Also look at the manual page for `?chisq.test`. You are not specifying it correctly.

Comment: About is just looking at  `chisq.test` the tactic vs sex and ignoring count values.  You need rearrange your data so that the columns are the Tactic categories, the rows are the sexes and the table being the N values.  See the `chisq.test` help look at the first example listed.  The example data seems to have zero or low counts for many of the values, Fisher's Exact test may be a better option.

Comment: Thanks for your help. How do I do a reduced dput (combo1) it's too long?

Comment: Isn't it only 1 + 26 + 2 + 15 = 44 lines with two columns? That is not too long. If there are more columns, leave them out: `dput(combo1[, c("Sex", "Tactic")]`.

Comment: ```{r}
dput(combo1[, c("Sex", "Tactic")]
``` Error: unexpected symbol in:
"dput(combo1[, c("Sex", "Tactic")]
dput"

Comment: Should have been `dput(combo1[, c("Sex", "Tactic")])` with a closing parenthesis at the end.

Comment: Thanks, https://stackoverflow.com/users/1580645/dcarlson. Just added data to the question above at the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now we can create a table and compute Chi square:

```
tbl <- xtabs(~Sex+Tactic, combo1)
tbl
#    Tactic
# Sex EstRes Migr OcRes
#   F      1   26     2
#   M      0   15     0
```

Notice there are very small cell counts in 4 of the 6 cells. A standard Chi square test will report a problem:

```
chisq.test(tbl)
# 
#   Pearson's Chi-squared test
# 
# data:  tbl
# X-squared = 1.6653, df = 2, p-value = 0.4349
# 
# Warning message:
# In chisq.test(tbl) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

This is not really a problem since the p-value is much greater than .05 so we cannot reject the null hypothesis. You can have R use Monte Carlo simulation to estimate a p-value:

```
chisq.test(tbl, simulate.p.value=TRUE)
# 
#   Pearson's Chi-squared test with simulated p-value (based on 2000 replicates)
# 
# data:  tbl
# X-squared = 1.6653, df = NA, p-value = 0.6922
```

As expected, the p-value is even larger.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant !https://stackoverflow.com/users/1580645/dcarlson. I can only hope to have your R flare someday! I see you are a retired archeologist; I bet that was a fascinating career (and lot's of hard work too, I suspect). I am a PhD using fish otoliths to determine migration and connectivity in predatory fish. I understand toliths are used in archeology too!